"[SC] DeleteService SUCCESS [SC] StartService FAILED with error 4294967201" Android Emulator hypervisor driver on Windows 11
I just installed Flutter and Android Studio. I want to start building mobile apps but I can't seem to get past the Android Studio setup because of this error:

I am using Windows 11. I already have Virtualization turned on:

Please help me. I really want to start building mobile applications.
My processor is AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics, 3.90 GHz.
What I tried:

Closing then Opening Android Studio
Reinstalling Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver on the SDK Manager (unclicking and clicking the checkbox beside it)
Turning my PC Off and On
Turning my Virtualization On then Restarting
I went through the solutions I found online from those who have the same question as me answered, but they do not work. I fear that they might be outdated.


This question is similar to: Can't install Android Emulator for AMD Processors. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
